# I am getting null values for the search parameters in my controller while clicking Forward button of Pagination in my GSP page

Tags: grails

I am using < g:paginate > tag for pagination functionality in my GSP page as given below:

```
 <g:paginate next="Forward" prev="Back" maxsteps="0" max="${max}"
 offset ="${offset}" controller="job" action="getEmployee"
 total="${employeeCount}"/>
```

Here value of offset, max and employeeCount is acquired from controller. In my GSP page, I have search fields like Name, Age etc in my form. When I click search button with some value Name or Age, I get data with multiple page displayed in my screen. When I click "Forward" button, the value for the search parameter (Name, Age) is null when I debugged and saw in jobController. So, I am getting exception.How can I pass my search parameters to the controller on clicking Forward button so that I can add these values in search criteria? Please help me with this condition. Currently I am accessing the parameters in controller by using code:

```
def name = params.name // this gives me null value
def age = params.age // this gives me null value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, take a look at the documentation for the [pagination](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Tags/paginate.html) tag.

You'll notice that there is this:

> params (optional) - A Map of request parameters

Now, if you simply want to include the parameters that were used when the GSP was rendered you could try adding the `params` attribute like this:

```
<g:paginate params="${params}" next="Forward" prev="Back" maxsteps="0" max="${max}"
 offset ="${offset}" controller="job" action="getEmployee"
 total="${employeeCount}"/>
```

Of course, this all depends on your requirements which you didn't make very clear.